# How to change timezone of already created docker container Wildfly Server?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jboss, timezone, wildfly

How can I change the timezone of wildfly server which already created as a docker container, to the UTC time?
Currently, I have one solution by creating a Docker container again and set UTC when creating.
I use wildfly version 13.

Comment: Deleting and recreating Docker containers is extremely routine (you'd need to do this if there was a critical security update in the underlying JVM or application server, for example); is there a reason you can't do this?

Comment: Because our server administrator doesn't like the solution of creating container again for changing the timezone , that's why I ask in the community